# reading an int from a file with read()

Tags: c, low-level

I'm working on a C programming assignment where we are only allowed to use lower level file IO commands (so no `fprintf()` or `fscanf()` function calls) to read and write a file.

In one section of the code I write a string to a file of 128 characters and right next to it I write an integer. I am able to use `pread` to `read` the string of characters alright but I get a "bad address" error when I use `pread` again to read the integer:

```
if(pread(heap, structure->str, STRING_MAX_LEN, 0) < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    printf("read str\n");
}

if(pread(file, structure->size, 1, STRING_MAX_LEN + 1) < 0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("read size\n"); 
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is `structure->size` an `int*`?  If it's just an `int` then you'd need to pass its address with `&`.

**Edit**: and as said by others, "1" is almost certainly not the number of bytes in your int, though it could be - you should probably use `sizeof()`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a 1 as the size of the integer. Unless it is a char, you are doing it wrong.

What is `structure->size`? What type?

EDIT

Since that you are in fact writing an int, you should use `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(structure->size)`.

You should also pass the address to the variable, and not it's value, using the `&` operator, so your line would be like:

```
if (pread(file, &structure->size, sizeof(structure->size), STRING_MAX_LEN + 1) < 0) { 
    return 0; 
} 
else { 
    printf("read size\n"); 
}
```

Comment: The type of structure->size is an integer. I've tried setting its size to sizeof(int) before but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sizeof` rather than hardcoding the size. Let the compiler work for you.

Second, the 2nd argument of [`pread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) looks to be a pointer to the buffer you intend to fill. You're passing the int field itself (by value) — usually, the C compiler is more than happy to treat an int as a pointer. You need to pass the int field **by reference**, so that `pread` has a pointer to the int it's supposed to fill with octets. You get the memory access violation (bad address) because the value of int field you're passing by value, treated as an address point to a memory location, you're not allowed to touch.

The first `pread()` works because (I suspect) that `structure->str` is either a `char*` or an an array of chars, which will get treated as an pointer.

```
if ( pread(heap,structure->str,STRING_MAX_LEN,0) < 0 )
{
  return -1;
}
else
{
  printf("read str\n");
}

if ( pread(file,&(structure->size), sizeof(structure->size) , STRING_MAX_LEN + 1 ) < 0 )
{
  return 0 ;
}
else
{
  printf("read size\n");
}
```